# Axis labels shifts off centre when using the xscale function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a plot to go into a report that needs to have the horizontal width increased, whilst maintaining the original vertical height. I am currently using the an `xscale=1.7`, however this shifts the horizontal axis label to the right of the plot area. I have tried using the `width=0.7\textwidth` but this increases the height of the plot to a ridiculous amount.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]% change in entropy
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xscale=1.7, xlabel=No. of Elements, ystep=1, xstep=2, xmin=0, xmax=16, ymin=0, ymax=3, ylabel= $\Delta S_{mix} (R)$]
\addplot+[color=black,smooth,mark=none]file{Data/Entropy_of_Mixing.txt};
\draw(axis cs: 2,0)--(axis cs: 2,1);
\draw(axis cs: 5,0)--(axis cs: 5,1.8);
\draw(axis cs: 13,0)--(axis cs: 13,2.8);
\node [text width= 1.5cm, text centered](a) at(axis cs: 1,0.75){Low Entropy};
\node [text width= 1.5cm, text centered](a) at(axis cs: 3.6,0.75){Medium Entropy};
\node [text width= 1.5cm, text centered](a) at(axis cs: 9,0.75){High Entropy};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Change in mixing entropy with number of principal elements}
\label{EntropyGraph}
\end{figure}

\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! I would just specify both `height` and `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `xscale=1.7` with `x post scale=1.7`.